# <authentication mode="forms"> configuration error on Godaddy Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I deployed a web application in Godaddy Hosting and created a virtual directory also. But when I try to access the application via URL, I get this following error

---

> `Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

Source Error:

`</assemblies>`
`</compilation>`
`<authentication mode="Forms">`
`<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />`

### `</authentication>`

I tried to google it and almost most of the answers are related to virtual directory. I have attached my web.config here.

I checked with the hosting support also, but they say, it could be coding error. So let me know, if I have to think in other prespective.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
`<configuration>`
   `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data            source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated     Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="fbpmProjectDetailsEntities"        connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ProjectDetail.csdl|res://*/Models.ProjectDetail.ss    dl|res://*/Models.ProjectDetail.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection     string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\fbpm.mdf;integrated     security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="fbpmUserEntities"      connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.UserModel.csdl|res://*/Models.UserModel.ssdl|res:/    /*/Models.UserModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection      string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\fbpm.mdf;integrated     security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="fbpmUserPaySchedEntities"      connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.UserPaymentSchedule.csdl|res://*/Models.UserPaymentSchedule.ssdl|res://*/Models.UserPaymentSchedule.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provide    r connection string=&quot;data     source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\fbpm.mdf;integrated security=True;user     instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"
      name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
          <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
          <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule"     type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
          <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
          <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule"     />
      </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   <!--<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />-->
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>`
```

---

Please help me to identify the issue.

Thanks, Senti

Comment: _Is_ your virtual directory configured as an application? There's a difference between a virtual directory and a virtual directory that's configured as an application. Right-click on your virtual directory in IIS and there should be either "Convert to Application", or "Manage Application" (if it's already an application)

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie, I tried to check the options for manage application or to convert the virtual directory to application, but in godaddy control panel, there is no such options.

Comment: why is the configuration tag in single quotes?  why is the connections string tag in single quotes

Comment: @Matt8541. Ignore that, that is something that i tried to format the code in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the real problem is the element before authentication, which is compilation.  This suggests that the targetFramework attribute may actually be the culprit, which in itself suggests that you may not have configured the IIS application pool to use .NET v4, but rather v2.0

Comment: ... If that doesn't do it, check the managed pipeline mode on the pool. Since your `<modules>` are within `<system.webServer>`, you [should be using an integrated managed pipeline](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the directory that you have your files in can be accessed by the IIS, this error occurs when the IIS can access the folder. just change the permissions to give access to the folder by IUSR and IIS_IUSR